# unity2d not rendering on phone correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine

Just started in Unity I'm trying to make a platform game. But having issues with aligning the bottom of the platforms with the bottom of the phone screen. Everything looks fine on the Scene windows but is not right on the Game window or on the phone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, i guess. it was the camera, I reset it and noticed the camera view was off so i was able to move it to fix it.